# NativeScript Camera takePicture method not returning promise in Android (but does in iOS)

Tags: android, camera, nativescript

Running the test-camera example [see nativesript-camera repo](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-camera/blob/master/examples/CameraTest/app/main-page.ts), everything works just fine in the iOS emulator and the image (selected from the gallery) is displayed on the screen. But when I test this same code running the Android emulator, after the camera opens and I snap a photo and click on save, the photo does not display on the screen. So I tested by adding a console.log right after the promise should return to see what I'm getting back:

```
takePicture({width: 180, height: 180, keepAspectRatio: false, saveToGallery: saveToGallery}).
        then((imageAsset) => {
            console.log("IMAGE ASSET", imageAsset);
            let source = new imageSourceModule.ImageSource();
            source.fromAsset(imageAsset).then((source) => {
                console.log(`Size: ${source.width}x${source.height}`);
            });
            page.bindingContext.set("cameraImage", imageAsset);
        }, 
        (err) => {
            console.log("Error -> " + err.message);
        });
```

The IMAGE ASSET console log never shows in terminal, I mean nothing. Not even the string I passed, and there are no errors. The console.log does show in terminal when I run the app in the iOS simulator, but in Android nothing. I'm using the Android Studio virtual device (a Nexus 5X running Android 7.1).

I tried to search online to see if others have run into this issue. Couldn't find anything. Has anyone run into this and be able to fix this?

=== UPDATE ===

So I went ahead and created a new project and added the takePicture method inside. It's now returning the promise, but I'm getting the following error on Android simulator:

```
An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onScanCompleted failed

TypeError: trace.isEnabled is not a function
File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.cameraproject/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-camera/nativescript-camera.js, line: 63, column: 50

StackTrace: 
    Frame: function:'onScanCompleted', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.cameraproject/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-camera/nativescript-camera.js', line: 63, column: 51


    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    at com.tns.Runtime.access$2400(Runtime.java:33)
    at com.tns.Runtime$3.run(Runtime.java:1214)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

The error goes away when I set saveToGallery to false ...

Comment: nope, that works for me, ive used the camera quite a bit

Comment: Oh wow, well that's good to know. @mast3rd3mon, the camera example works for you on Android? You can snap a photo and display that photo on screen? It works for me on iOS only. Do you have your code structured differently?

Comment: Just noticed something else. The nativescript-camera example using Angular works just fine on Android emulator and on device. It's the non-Angular example that's not working.

Comment: Since the original issue was fixed with the changes I proposed; you should mark that as the accepted answer and create a new question with the new issue.   By doing it this way you can confuse people coming here in the future...

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have a coding mistake;

```
takePicture({width: 180, height: 180, keepAspectRatio: false, saveToGallery: saveToGallery}).
        then((imageAsset) => {
            console.log("IMAGE ASSET", imageAsset);
            let source = new imageSourceModule.ImageSource();
            source.fromAsset(imageAsset).then((source) => {
                console.log(`Size: ${source.width}x${source.height}`);
            });
            page.bindingContext.set("cameraImage", imageAsset);
        }, 
        (err) => {
            console.log("Error -> ",  err, err.stack);
        });
```

I'm pretty sure your `error` routine will be throwing an error the way it is written, and when it throws an error inside a catch of a promise it is silently eaten.

If I had a guess to the root cause, since you mention Android 7, I would venture a guess your app doesn't have the permissions it needs.  So it is throwing an error, which then hits your error routine which throws an error making everything just vanish....

---

**Updated answer for your new issue**

For you to use the NativeScript-Camera v3.0.0 you **must** be using TNS 3.0.0 core modules.   If you want to use TNS core modules 2.5.0 (or before) you need to use NativeScript-Camera v0.0.8 or earlier...

Comment: Hmmm. I do call `requestPermissions();` and when i first boot up the app, it asks for permission, which I grant.  Also, in terms of throwing the error, even if it did, should it log it to the console? I'm not getting anything logged to the console.

Comment: Did you try the rewrite version (I posted above): 
`console.log("Error ->", err, err.stack)`
 and see if that reports an error

Comment: And no if the console in your version of the source is throwing an error like I think it is, you won't get anything logged; it will look like the promise didn't work or do anything.

Comment: I did try your error console.log version. My guess is that's the issue, because the exact same code works just fine when i run `tns run ios`, meaning that (for iOS simulator), it'll allow me to select an image from the gallery and then display it in the view, but when I run `tns run android` with the same code base, the camera opens, I can snap a photo, select that photo, and then the photo doesn't bind to the view. In trying to debug in developer tools, I notice that the promise doesn't return the asset for some reason.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Once my app updates, the promise is not returned back

Comment: Add a try catch around that code to see what error.